# Как определить по какому QLabel сработал mousePressEvent?

Tags: python, qt, gui, pyqt5, mouse-event

Всем добра.

Пишу интерфейс на `PyQt5`. Есть `QFrame`, в котором расположено 9 `QLabel` с `QPixmap(QImage)`. При клике на изображение (`QLabel`), вызываю функцию.

На данный момент, проблема состоит в том, что реализовал я все очень криво, совсем не `'pythonic way'` (хотя я, как самоучка, обычно не парюсь по поводу красоты, так как не знаю, что это(Я старый солдат, и не знаю слов любви, донна Роза ...)). 
В `__init__()` главного окна я пишу вот такую лабуду:

```
    self.ui.label_gv_0.mousePressEvent = self.set_img_0
    self.ui.label_gv_1.mousePressEvent = self.set_img_1
    self.ui.label_gv_2.mousePressEvent = self.set_img_2
    self.ui.label_gv_3.mousePressEvent = self.set_img_3
    self.ui.label_gv_4.mousePressEvent = self.set_img_4
    self.ui.label_gv_5.mousePressEvent = self.set_img_5
    self.ui.label_gv_6.mousePressEvent = self.set_img_6
    self.ui.label_gv_7.mousePressEvent = self.set_img_7
    self.ui.label_gv_main.mousePressEvent = self.set_img_m
```

Соответственно приходится создавать 9 одинаковых функций, что есть позор. Вот пример:

```
def set_img_0(self, event):
    global last_buffered_img
    last_buffered_img = nine['img_0']
    self.show_img(nine['img_0'])
    self.del_img()
    self.nine_in_one()
```

Как я понял, из `QMouseEvent`, вытащить информацию можно только о координатах, но не о конкретном объекте. Подскажите, как поступать в таких ситуациях? Как отловить, по какому конкретно изображению кликнули, или как передать в вызываемый метод параметр с именем изображения при таком отлове события? Как вообще в питоне группировать подобные вещи, чтобы получалось красиво, кратко и элегантно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно для группировки множества виджетов в `Qt` используется [`QSignalMapper`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) и работа идет с сигналами и слотами. В принципе требуется что-то типа такого

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
#у меня здесь только четвертый стоит, а так примерно также все будет
import sys
#создаем собственный класс под метки
class MyLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal() #новый сигнал под клик
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QLabel.__init__(self, *args)
    #обработчик мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.clicked.emit()# вызывает сигнал
        QtWidgets.QLabel.mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent)

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        lt = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        l1 = MyLabel("l1")
        l2 = MyLabel("l2")
        lt.addWidget(l1)
        lt.addWidget(l2)
        #создаем маппер
        smap = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
        #привязываем первую метку
        l1.clicked.connect(smap.map)#соеденить
        smap.setMapping(l1, 1)#задать индекс
        #привязываем вторую метку
        l2.clicked.connect(smap.map)
        smap.setMapping(l2, 2)
        #соединяем маппер со слотом
        smap.mapped.connect(self.on_click)

    #событие
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_click(self, index):
        print(str(index))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MyWidget()
widget.showNormal ()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Надо мне, в конце концов, разобраться с декораторами, а то как от волков бегу...
Правда, поскольку я, надеюсь, пока, являюсь 'coding monkey',  опять вылезла проблема разрастания кода. Поскольку я использую QtDesigner для моделирования интерфейса, приходится в основном файле логики, переопределять QLabel`ы в формате self.ui.label_gv_0 = MyLabel(self.ui.frame_GV)
        self.ui.label_gv_0.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(68, 94, 100);")
        self.ui.label_gv_0.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.ui.gridLayout_32.addWidget(self.ui.label_gv_0,5,1,1,1)

Comment: В QtDesigner контекстное меню по виджету->Преобразовать в